# How to calculate final price with forEach and Mongoose queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a difficult final-price calculating issues with Mongoose Queries. I have three functions. This one get's an ID and external quantity, finds the material price, and finally mulitply it.

```
async function getPrivatePrice(id, quantity) {
  try {
    let piece = await Piece.findOne({'_id': id}).select({"meterage": 1, "material": 1, "_id" : 0}).then((piece) => {
      return piece;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    let price = await Material.findOne({'_id': piece.material}).select({"_id" : 0, "price" : 1}).then((price) => {
      return price;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    let final_raw = piece.meterage * price.price;
    let final_price = final_raw * quantity;
    return { final_price : final_price }

  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I'm really having difficulties with the second part of the code, because I need to get many id's from another function, so, I decided to use a forEach to call this function, and get all these prices and put them in an array, but I don't know how to return it.

```
async function getFinalCost(pieces) {
  let total_cost = [];
  try {
    pieces.forEach(async (response) => {
      let query = await PieceController.getPrivatePrice(response["_id"], response["quantity"]).then((piecePrice) => {
        return piecePrice["final_price"];
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      total_cost.push(query);
    });
    return total_cost;

  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I like to know how to get that array here:

```
function createProduct(req, res) {

  let params = req.body;
  let product = new Product();
  product.name = params.name;
  product.reference = params.reference;
  product.pieces = params.pieces;
  product.color = params.color;
  let piece_price = getFinalCost(product.pieces);
  console.log(piece_price); //Outputs Promise { { total_array: [] } }
}
```

Comment: So what is the end goal here? `pieces` is an array containing `_id` and `quantity` values, and you need to return the total cost added together or what exactly? Suffice to say you're going about it the wrong way, so it's better to show your input and expected output.

Comment: The basic fix is `let piece_price = await getFinalCost(product.pieces);` because you misunderstood the concept that you don't actually resolve values "within" a promise. However this code really could do with some guidance on a total refactor.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I still get the same error with `{total_array : []`, I need to know first how to return the `total_cost` only after the forEach is completed

Comment: That's why I'm asking you for the additional detail. You don't need a `forEach()` here as you can actually ask the database to do this without all the requests. This should require **one** async call only.

Comment: You are right, pieces is an array containing `_id` and `quantity`, when they go through the forEach, they are executed at `getPrivatePrice` as you can see, that function finds the `Piece`  `Material`, and meterage, then the price of the `Material` and mutiplies `price * meterage`, and finally that value with the quantity... So, the function returns that number, I need to have all that numbers to use it later, or maybe get a final price for the `createProduct` function

Comment: So an array of "totals" for each provided `pieces` entry? Sound right?

Comment: Not exacty, Its like this: `request (Array of pieces with _id and Quantity` -> `forEach to get ((pieceMeterage * materialPrice) * quantity)` -> `every price that getFinalCost gets, will be inside an array` or maybe make a summation of all that numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly need to refactor your code. What I would do is use something like bluebird to run a map over the pieces list like so.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

async function getMoreProductInfo(id) {
    try{
        const productInfo = await Piece.findOne({'_id': id}).select({"meterage": 1, "material": 1, "_id" : 0});
        const materialInfo = await Material.findOne({'_id': productInfo.material}).select({"_id" : 0, "price" : 1});
        return { productInfo, materialInfo };
    } catch(e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

async function calculatePrices(pieces) {
    try {
        const priceList = await Promise.map(pieces, async (piece) => {
            const { productInfo, materialInfo } = await getMoreProductInfo(piece._id);
            return materialInfo.price * piece.quantity * productInfo.meterage;
        });
        return priceList
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I clearly cannot test this code as is..but I think it should be pretty straightforward to tell whats going on(I think)

Comment: That worked, but I'm still needing to get a summatory of every oject of `priceList` array

Comment: Easy Peasy. You have every information you need in the price list array to work that out. You can run a reduce operation on the array to get a sum of all the items https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce